# How to use .innerHTML with a var created by let

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a very simple app in javascript in order to get rgb color to be divided by 255. I want the result to appear on the index.html page but it hasn't worked can anyone tell me how to fix it.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <p id="red"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
let red = prompt("Enter the red number here");
let green = prompt("Enter the green number here");
let blue = prompt("Enter the blue number here.");

let resultR = red/255; 
let resultG = green/255;
let resultB = blue/255;

document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = resultR;
```

Comment: `#red` does not exist in the HTML at the time the script is run. Give your script tag the `defer` attribute.

Comment: @CertainPerformance or move it to after the p

Comment: Feel free to delete this...

Answer (score -2):

It works fine though...

The problem may be that you call the JavaScript before Html so can't find the element.

```js
let red = prompt("Enter the red number here");
let green = prompt("Enter the green number here");
let blue = prompt("Enter the blue number here.");

let resultR = red/255; 
let resultG = green/255;
let resultB = blue/255;

document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = resultR;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>app</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<p id="red"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excuse me, he doesn't say where he put the JavaScript code. It doesn't make sense to vote down.

Comment: Terry Wei , someone here thinks he is the best, lol

Comment: I don't know If there's wrong to know why be voted down. If you have a clue, please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Terry Wei, i too dont know,